# Magento direct SQL query and magento orm basic

Tags: sql, orm, magento-1.9

I am little bit confuse. I am using magento orm basic like `Mage::getModel('test/test')` and I search that also use direct SQL query use for insert,update and delete so my question is which one is better and if I use direct SQL query so any arise security issue in future or secure direct SQL query in magento ? Which one is better both of them ? Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using Mage::getModel() for most/all operations. When you have model rewrites, for example, you need to use Mage::getModel() for those rewrites to work.

Additionally, using Mage::getModel() helps to ensure that any event observers are fired off when necessary. When you use direct SQL, you are circumventing Magento's tried and tested methods and you enter into dangerous territory if you are not quite sure what you are doing.

Stick to Magento's native methods whenever possible to maintain the integrity of your data.

Comment: Thanks you for answer but what is use of direct SQL ? Any purpose in magento of direct SQL ?

Comment: direct sql would be typing out a statement like `INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity ....`. Magento has an architecture in which just about all database operations that you need are contained within methods. In Magento, when you interact with the database, many times, other logic needs to be executed as well. Magento's native db methods take this into account, with a focus on keeping your database interactions safer, meaning less likely to have a mistake that will screw up the database.